# Index on HAVING?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my basic understanding of an index, the index is used on a column in a `WHERE` clause. Since the `HAVING` clause is similar to a `WHERE` clause applied after a `GROUP BY` statement, does an index have the same effect on that? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE full_name = 'Bob Jones'
--> index on full_name would be beneficial here
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE first_name = 'Bob' 
GROUP BY
    height HAVING height > 72
```

In this second query, would an index on both first_name and height improve the performance? Which index would be more important, or are they roughly the equivalent? Also, do indexes improve `GROUP BY` performance as well (regardless of a `HAVING`)?

Comment: Since height is not an aggregate function it doesn't make any sense to use HAVING. Just use WHERE instead.

Comment: [GROUP BY can use index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `HAVING` clause is essentially the last thing done to filter a query's results before they're sent off to the client. It's only useful if you need to filter on the results of an aggregate function, whose value can NOT be available during the row-level filtering that `WHERE` clauses do.

Essentially, a `HAVING` clause can be seen as applying another query, turning your main query into a subquery.

e.g.

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometable
HAVING somefield = X
```

is really no different that

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT ...
   FROM sometable
)
WHERE somefield = X
```

If the field you're filtering with the HAVING is **NOT** a derived field (aggregate value, calculated field, etc...) then you're almost certainly better off doing the filtering at the WHERE level, which keeps unecessary rows from being loaded off disk in the first place.

Since having is applied last, rows will be loaded from disk, then possibly discarded if they don't match the HAVING criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, this helps me understand `HAVING` much better. In other words, since you only use `HAVING` on a derived field, it would never make sense to use an index on it, correct?

Comment: it's not necessary to use it only on derived fields. it'll act like a regular `where` clause as well, it'll just be much less efficient. But yeah, you can't have indexes on calculated/derived fields, because they're generated on-the-fly as the query executes. If the value doesn't change often, you CAN denormalize the table and store the calculated value into a field, which then CAN be indexed.